# Tracking different clip to different camera

Tags: tracking

my question is how I can apply a different clip camera motion to another camera. I manage to import various clips in the motion track tab and track them but there is no way I can solve the track to a different camera, every time I select the different camera and make it active the tracker always solve the tracking data of the new clip to the same camera.

I want to have multiple cameras in my scene with different camera motion tracking data.